# Unable to Import node modules angular 6 project

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I am trying import rxjs operator in my project but surprisingly I am getting below error.

```
import switchMap  from 'rxjs/operators/switchMap';
Unable to load 'rxjs/operator/switchMap' which is required by dynamic module 'UiModule'. The package does not include this module.
```

I have tried with other libraries but same result. Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: maybe it's a good idea to include your import statement and the relevant parts of your package.json

Comment: try it this way `import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators'`

Comment: @ArturNiko tried same result